# TypeError in Codality Python MaxProductOfThree

Tags: python, typeerror

I was practising the following exercise of Codality lessons in Python:
Your goal is to find the maximal product of any triplet.

```
Write a function:

def solution(A)

that, given a non-empty array A, returns the value of the maximal product of any triplet.

For example, given array A such that:

  A[0] = -3
  A[1] = 1
  A[2] = 2
  A[3] = -2
  A[4] = 5
  A[5] = 6
the function should return 60, as the product of triplet (2, 4, 5) is maximal.

def solution(A):
    A.sort()
    N=len(A)
    P1=A[N-1]*A[0]*A[1]
    P2=A[N-1]*A[N-2]*A[N-3]
    return max(P1, P2)

print(solution[4,2,2,5,1,5,8])
```

I have face this error while running the code : `TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable`
Can you please help me out in fixing the code?

Comment: ```print(solution[4,2,2,5,1,5,8])``` you forgot to add a ```()```. To call a function, you have to ```()```. Doing ```function[]``` tell python to take a part of it, which apparently is not possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
print(solution([4,2,2,5,1,5,8]))
```

This is what you're missing

These added `()` is what tells the Python interpreter:
"Get what the `solution()` function returns when given `[4,2,2,5,1,5,8]` as the parameter.

Writing something like `solution[something]` means to subscript, or 'take some part out of' the `solution`, which is applicable to strings or lists for example, but not to functions, hence the error.

Comment: I'd appreciate it if you would `accept this answer` if you found it useful :)

Answer (score 1):

You should write it as `solution([A])` and not `solution[A]`.